# CI Is there a way to query custom order_by

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to customize the order_by query in MySQL or in CI ? Such as I want my column to be ordered by ('1', '11', '4', '2', '21', '3', '5', '7') So if I query it as ASC the result will show in the order of my customized order.

If it is not possible, what is the best workaround to get these order ? Hoping for a simple solution just using the MySQL query.

All answers and suggestions are greatly welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$this -> db -> order_by('FIELD ( table.id, 1, 11, 4,2,21,3,5,7 )');
```

[link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/1846)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Pure Mysql answer is yes you can order a field by a set list with the MYSQL `FIELD()` function

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE id IN ('1', '11', '4', '2', '21', '3', '5', '7')
ORDER BY FIELD(id, '1', '11', '4', '2', '21', '3', '5', '7')
```

Comment: I haven't tested but I wonder if those inverted commas implicitly cast the remaining data as strings.

Comment: @Strawberry you are probably right. so you are saying the single quotes are redundent

Comment: I'm certainly saying that. I'm also speculating as to whether they alter the result.